# I need to use grid to make a table with background image that is responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

-Simply my question is to make a table. I will give the photo that I need to make
[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXycU.png][1]][1]
the table is
** responsive**
** has an background image
** has multi columns and rows

It is very hard to me to handle it because some issues I face every time I try

Comment: Please put the code you have tried into your question and describe what isn’t working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the code I can't do is to make that photo

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp

Comment: I understand that you can't as yet get the output look you want (that's why you are asking a question!) but you say you face issues when  you try, so please show us what you have tried so we can help you.